# Find files last modified in August

Tags: linux, performance, grep

I am currently trying to use ls-l and grep to find all the files in the directory /etc that were last modifed in August. 
I have a hint to try and look for the case sensitive string 'Aug'.

I tried the command

```
ls -l /etc | grep -E 'Aug'
```

but this returns nothing.

My thought process was cat the contents of the directory then look for the string 'Aug' to find the files modified in August. 
Any help would be great as this is my first ever post here

Comment: Are you sure there are any files modified in August in `/etc`? Also, do you mean any August, or just the last one?

Comment: Hey choroba, I had a look and couldn't see any files that were last modified in August, however i am not sure. I am looking for anything modified in August so i presume the last August

Comment: Normaly, you'd use `find` with its `-mtime` option to find files with a specified modification time.

Comment: *Never* use `ls` for this; `ls` is intended for human consumption. *Always* use [`find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/find.1.html).

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 0):

Guys thanks for your advice. 
Sorry if I wasnt being clear enough as my linux skills are quite limited.

I used:

```
find /etc -type f -name 'Aug'
```

This seems to have worked for me. Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for your input. I will try to stop asking silly questions lol.

Comment: That will find files with the string `Aug` in their name, not files modified in August.